# Concat a single Sheet from Multiple Excel Files whilst handling files with missing sheets

Tags: python, pandas

Good night, stack!

I am facing an issue related to pandas library on Python. Im trying to automate a mass append/concat on multiple excel files (with multiple sheets). However, i can not figure out how to simply skip the files which does not contains that especified sheet_name. Any ideas? My code is as below:

PS1: I had to insert a break to end the iteration as soon as the code was reading every sheet in every xlsx file.

PS2: The error is: "XLRDError: No sheet named <'CSNSC 2020'>".

PS3: I was able to figure out a way: by positioning a try right after the loop for, and an exception for the error. However, for this, i need to be pretty the rest of the code works.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import os

    path = r'C:/Users/Thiago/Desktop/Backup/Python/Files test append xlsx'
    files = os.listdir(path)

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    xlsx_files = [path + '\\' + f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']

    for i in xlsx_files:
       xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(i)
          for name in xlsx.sheet_names:
             data = pd.read_excel(i, header = 1, sheet_name = "CSNSC 2020")
             data['File'] = i
             print(i)
             df = df.append(data)
             break

    df = df[['Dt. Ref.','Convênio','Tipo de Atendimento','Venc.']]
    df.head()

    df = df.dropna(subset=['Convênio'])
    df.head()

    df.to_excel(r'C:/Users/Thiago/Desktop/Backup/Python/Files test append xlsx/out.xlsx')
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this simple function to concat excel files and handle excel files with missing work-sheets. feel free to adapt it to your own use-case

the main thing to note is the `try` and `except` to handle the errors.

## Modules.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from xlrd import XLRDError
```

## In Action

```
concat_excels(src,'Sheet2',trg)
No sheet named <'Sheet2'> in file_0.xlsx, skipping
No sheet named <'Sheet2'> in file_1.xlsx, skipping
No sheet named <'Sheet2'> in file_2.xlsx, skipping
No sheet named <'Sheet2'> in file_3.xlsx, skipping
No sheet named <'Sheet2'> in file_4.xlsx, skipping
No sheet named <'Sheet2'> in file_5.xlsx, skipping
No sheet named <'Sheet2'> in file_6.xlsx, skipping
No sheet named <'Sheet2'> in file_7.xlsx, skipping
No sheet named <'Sheet2'> in file_8.xlsx, skipping
No sheet named <'Sheet2'> in file_9.xlsx, skipping
File Saved to C:\Users\DataNovice\OneDrive\Documents\2020\python\file_io_ops\move_files_test
```

## Function.

```
def concat_excels(source_path, sheet_name, target_path):

    """ 
    A simple script to find excel files in a target 
    location and merge them into a single file.
    You need Python installed along with Pandas.
    pathlib is available in Python 3.4 + 
    error handling added.
    """

    # create list for excel files.
    excel_files = [file for file in Path(source_path).glob("*.xlsx")]

    # create empty list to store each individual dataframe.
    excel_dataframe = []

    # loop through our file to read each file and append it to our list.

    for file in excel_files:
        try:
            df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=sheet_name)
            df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()  # lowercase all columns
            df.columns = (
                df.columns.str.strip()
            )  # remove any trailing or leading white space.
            excel_dataframe.append(df)
        except XLRDError as err:
            print(f"{err} in {file.name}, skipping")

    try:
        final_dataframe = pd.concat(excel_dataframe, axis=1)
        final_dataframe.to_excel(target_path + "\master_file.xlsx", index=False)

        print(f"File Saved to {target_path}")

    except ValueError as err_2:
        print(
            f"No Sheets Matched in any of your excel files, are you sure {sheet_name} is correct?"
        )
    return excel_dataframe
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Datanovice! I editted my post to say that i have figured out a solution just like this: using try and exception. =) you made it!